# Angular2 Hybrid mode : loading Ng1 components dynamically

Tags: angular, ng-upgrade

I am trying to load the ng1 components dynamically inside a ng2 parent component using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`. Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/HADJILztGEELg5lavfvP?p=preview

However it throws following exception:

```
ViewWrappedException {_wrapperMessage: "Error in ./DynamicComponent class DynamicComponent - inline template:0:27", _originalException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of null
    at new UpgradeNg1ComponentAdapter (https://npmcd…, _originalStack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of null?  …ular/core@2.0.0-rc.2/bundles/core.umd.js:8276:49)", _context: DebugContext, _wrapperStack: "Error: Error in ./DynamicComponent class DynamicCo…DNGqj1u/src/dynViewComponent.ts!transpiled:84:45)"}_context: DebugContext_originalException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of null
```

Here is the ng1-comp.js

```
define( ['bootstrap'], 
function( ng1 ) {
  'use strict';

    ng1.ngModule.component('ng1Comp', {
      template:'<h1>NG1 Comp </h1>',
    });
} );
```

Here is the dynamic Loader :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>This is dynamic view container</div>
  `
})
export class App {
  private _componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;
  private vcRef:any;  
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: 
  ComponentResolver){
      this.vcRef = this.viewContainerRef;
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(){
    if (this._componentRef) {
        this._componentRef.destroy();
        this._componentRef = null;
    }

    System.import('js/ng1-comp.js');    

    const metadata = new ComponentMetadata({
        directives: [upgradeAdapter.instance.upgradeNg1Component('ng1Comp') ],
        selector: 'dynamic-content',
        template: '<ng1-comp></ng1-comp>'
    });
    this.createComponentFactory(this.resolver, metadata)
      .then(factory => {
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], 
          this.vcRef.parentInjector);
        this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
      });
  }

  private createComponentFactory(resolver: ComponentResolver, 
      metadata: ComponentMetadata): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
    const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);
    return resolver.resolveComponent(decoratedCmp);
  }

}
```

Appreciate any pointers..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue with `UpgradeAdapter`. It requires all the NG1 upgrades be done before app is bootsrapped. The work around is to upgrade all the NG1 components being loaded dynamically to be pre-upgraded before `UpgradeAdapter.bootstrap()` is called.

Issue [#9959](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9959) Logged with angualr2 github.
Meantime here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ChPTVb0lI6wxM5QjVYoS?p=preview) with workaround.